# Sidebar inside content

Tags: php, html, wordpress

On the following image you can see how the sidebar of my wordpress site has somehow found its way into the content:

[image]

I'm not sure how I move it out? I have a results.php file that calls the entire content section and the sidebar is not mentioned in there (I just turned the sidebar on in wordpress).

Any ideas on how I fix this?

Comment: The error is likely to be found in CSS of your theme.  You should provide some of your code. Store the page and show a minimal static HTML with CSS code reproducing the misbehavior. Strip out large contents to make it more readable.

Comment: It's as if it's being mixed into the columns on my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as you had added columns in a bootstrap framework grid design.
When doing so, you have to adapt the classes of all columns to fit your desired result. It might be applicable to redesign 2 main columns and divide one in nested columns. The sum of grid columns in a row should be 12. The class names like `.col-md-2` are similar to `<td colspan="2">` table cells.

See the [documentation example](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) and explanation of the [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) for further information.